# Changing colors in terminal output

Tags: command-line, colors, output

When i write scripts i want that some lines are colored in output. My questions is not about changing prompt (PS1) but for example how can i change that the output, let us say, "cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs" would be in red, for example.

Thx for answers

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [How can I print text in various colors?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips:

http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/output-color-on-bash-scripts-advanced/

You can change the output with: {ESC}[{attr};{bg};{256colors};{fg}m

Search for scripting tutorials for more details

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what tibike and enzotib said, to print some output in color - for example have the output of `cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` be in red you can use this set of commands:

```
tput setaf 1; cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs; tput sgr0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat .PS1 
   BLACK="\[\033[00;30m\]"
     RED="\[\033[00;31m\]"
   GREEN="\[\033[00;32m\]"
  YELLOW="\[\033[00;33m\]"
    BLUE="\[\033[00;34m\]"
 MAGENTA="\[\033[00;35m\]"
    CYAN="\[\033[00;36m\]"
   WHITE="\[\033[00;37m\]"

  BLACKb="\[\033[01;30m\]"
    REDb="\[\033[01;31m\]"
  GREENb="\[\033[01;32m\]"
 YELLOWb="\[\033[01;33m\]"
   BLUEb="\[\033[01;34m\]"
MAGENTAb="\[\033[01;35m\]"
   CYANb="\[\033[01;36m\]"
  WHITEb="\[\033[01;37m\]"

   BLANK="\[\033[00;00m\]"

export PS1="\w\n \[\033[01;32m\]rap\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\]"
export PS1="$BLACKb\h: $GREEN\w\n$BLACKb\$ $BLANK"
```

quick demo:

[image: COLARZ]